# How to put a div at the bottom center of the container

Tags: html, css

I know that there are a lot of questions like this, but nothing worked to keep the div at the center & bottom of the container.
I tried this method:

```
.element-to-stick-to-bottom {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}

.container-element {
position: relative;
}
```

which gave me this result:
[image]

IDK what's causing this, and I can't use `margin-left: 10%;` because the buttons have different lengths.
I can't use a different value for each button as well because then it will change between monitor sizes.
I need a solution to do this other than using `position: absolute;` - because for some reason, when I use this position on the divs - they shift to the right and it's kinda like `text-align: left` but the "starting point" is from the middle.

I've reviewed my code **a 1000** times (including the master page) and I can't find anything wrong. in any case, here's the CSS:

```css
table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
        padding: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    table {
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        overflow: auto;
    }    
    #services_table {
    table-layout: fixed;
    }

    #services_table td {
       /* height: 20px; */
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 25%;
    }
    .container{
        width: 100%;
        height: 490px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        /*position: relative;*/
    }
    #logo_container{
        height: 150px;
    }
    .button{
        width: auto;
        height: 34px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        border-radius: 180px;
        text-decoration: none;
          font-family: 'typo_light';
          font-size: 28px;
          display: inline-block;
          padding-left: 20px;
          padding-right: 20px;
          background-color: #f45e61;
          /*position: absolute;*/ /*causes the element to not be centered, ffs. needs fixing.*/
          /*bottom: 0;*/ /*doesnt work as intended*/
          position: absolute;
          /*bottom: 0;*/
    }
    #PLUS{
        margin-right: 5px;
        margin-left: -20px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 11%;
        height: 34px;
        border-radius: 180px;
        background-color: blue;
    }
    #LOGO_BUTTON{
        margin-left: 0px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 40px;
        width: auto;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
        /*margin-left: -8.3%;*/
    }
    #ONLY_TEXT{
        margin-left: -6px;
    }
    .description{
        text-decoration: none;
          font-family: 'typo_thin';
          font-size: 50px;
    }
    .inside_container{
        padding: 30px;
    }
    .dot {
      font-family: 'ormont';
    }
```

And the HTML:

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <table style="width:100%;" id="services_table">
  <tr>
    <td><center><div class="container"><div class="inside_container"><span class="description">We offer to "enhance" an already existing website<span class="dot">.</span><br>We will redesign your website, add JS, and some pazzaz<span class="dot">.</span><br>Do you already have a website that you feel like needs renovating?<br>Contact us<span class="dot">.</span><br></span><div class="button" id="enhance_button">enhance en existing site</div></div></div></center></td>
    <td><center><div class="container"><div class="button" id="design_button">design by request - from scratch</div></div></center></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="bottom"><center><div class="container"><div class="button" id="specific_button">build a specific feature</div></div></center></td>
    <td><center><div class="container"><div class="button" id="build_button">build an entire site with database from scratch</div></div></center></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th colspan="2"><center><div class="container" id="logo_container"><div class="button" id="LOGO_BUTTON"><span id="PLUS">+</span><span id="ONLY_TEXT"> added money: design a logo</span></div></div></center></th>
  </tr>
</table>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

container element must be relative position because child element must be positioned relatively to container element, then you can make left property 50%, it will position elements left side right in the middle of container, with transform property you pull 50% of the elements position left again, and it will stay right in the center of X axis

**Reference**: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem"></div>
</div>
```

```
.container {
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

.elem {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pLy9fjsu/

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript

```
// select all the elements you want stick to bottom center
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".element-to-stick-to-bottom")

// loop throw all the elements and set the left property to (50% width of the container - 50% width of the element
elements.forEach((el) => {
  el.style.left = "calc(50% - " + (el.offsetWidth / 2) + "px )"
})
```

Note: you need to keep the css position property as it is for both the container ( position: relative ) and for the element (position: absolute)

Answer (score -1):

Well maybe this might work. Try assigning the id of the element. Your code might be

```
<the element class="element-to-stick-to-bottom">
```

You can change this to

```
<the element class="element-to-stick-to-bottom">
```

Well it would be better if you provide the html code

Comment: What's the difference between the 2 lines?

Comment: I agree, without HTML code there is not much we can do to help